# Why does jar library work in Eclipse but not Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, jar

I have a jar library (specifically Rajawali v0.9) that works perfectly in Eclipse when using and compiling my project but Android Studio gives a ton of errors when trying to compile. Why is that and is there a way to bypass lint on specific jar library?

**EDIT**

Had to remove the manifest via gradle because of some mismatch but here is the logcat when I try to run the app:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load bufferutil from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pspdemocenter.graffitilwp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.pspdemocenter.graffitilwp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    at rajawali.util.BufferUtil.<clinit>(BufferUtil.java:16)
    at rajawali.Geometry3D.setVertices(Geometry3D.java:506)
    at rajawali.Geometry3D.setVertices(Geometry3D.java:494)
    at rajawali.Geometry3D.setData(Geometry3D.java:259)
    at rajawali.BaseObject3D.setData(BaseObject3D.java:177)
    at rajawali.BaseObject3D.setData(BaseObject3D.java:154)
    at rajawali.BaseObject3D.setData(BaseObject3D.java:171)
    at rajawali.BaseObject3D.<init>(BaseObject3D.java:114)
    at com.pspdemocenter.graffitilwp.MyRenderer.LoadSerializedMesh(MyRenderer.java:65)
    at com.pspdemocenter.graffitilwp.MyRenderer.initScene(MyRenderer.java:119)
    at rajawali.renderer.RajawaliRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(RajawaliRenderer.java:362)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1244)
```

Comment: what are those tons of errors? can you derive the most common out of it ?

Comment: https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I'm familiar with that link. I've been using Rajawali since it was Min3D. Years now. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use jar library in android studio like that :-

Step 1 : Now under your **`app folder`** you should see **`libs`**, if you don't see it, then create it .

Step 2 : **`Drag & Drop the .jar file here`**, you may be get a prompt **`"This file does not belong to the project"`**, just click **`OK`** Button .

Step 3 : Now you should see the jar file under libs folder, right click on the jar file and select **`"Add as library", Click OK for prompt "Create Library"`**

Step 4 : Now this **`jar`** has been added.

[image]